# Doesn't understand the window output with event time and watermark

Tags: apache-flink

I have following flink code that prints the content of the window that is based on event time and watermark. 4 seconds are allowed to be out of order,and window length is 8 seconds.

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.Date
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit

import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.TimeCharacteristic
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.timestamps.BoundedOutOfOrdernessTimestampExtractor
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala.function.WindowFunction
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala.{StreamExecutionEnvironment, _}
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.windowing.assigners.TumblingEventTimeWindows
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.windowing.time.Time
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.windowing.windows.TimeWindow
import org.apache.flink.util.Collector

object EventTimeWindowTest{
  def to_milli(str: String) =
    new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").parse(str).getTime

  def to_char(milli: Long) = {
    val date = if (milli <= 0) new Date(0) else new Date(milli)
    new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(date)
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
    env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime)
    env.setParallelism(1)
    val data = Seq(
      ("A", "2020-08-30 10:50:15"),
      ("A", "2020-08-30 10:50:11"),
      ("B", "2020-08-30 10:50:14"),
      ("B", "2020-08-30 10:50:09"),
      ("A", "2020-08-30 10:50:21"),
      ("A", "2020-08-30 10:50:10")
    )

    val stream = env.fromCollection(data).setParallelism(1).assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(new BoundedOutOfOrdernessTimestampExtractor[(String, String)](Time.seconds(4)) {
      override def extractTimestamp(evt: (String, String)): Long = to_milli(evt._2)
    }).keyBy(_._1)
      .window(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.of(8, TimeUnit.SECONDS)))
      .apply(new WindowFunction[(String, String), String, String, TimeWindow] {
        override def apply(key: String, window: TimeWindow, windowData: Iterable[(String, String)], out: Collector[String]): Unit = {
          val start = to_char(window.getStart)
          val end = to_char(window.getEnd)
          val sb = new StringBuilder
          sb.append(s"$key($start, $end):")
          windowData.foreach {
            e => sb.append(e._2 + ",")
          }
          out.collect(sb.toString().substring(0, sb.length - 1))
        }
      })
    stream.print().setParallelism(1)

    env.execute()

  }

}
```

With above code, the output is:

```
A(2020-08-30 10:50:08, 2020-08-30 10:50:16):2020-08-30 10:50:15,2020-08-30 10:50:11,2020-08-30 10:50:10
B(2020-08-30 10:50:08, 2020-08-30 10:50:16):2020-08-30 10:50:14,2020-08-30 10:50:09
A(2020-08-30 10:50:16, 2020-08-30 10:50:24):2020-08-30 10:50:21
```

I don't understand why `2020-08-30 10:50:10` for `A` is printed out,

for this event, the previous event `("A", "2020-08-30 10:50:21")` forwards the watermark to be
`2020-08-30 10:50:17`, hence flink should close the window `(2020-08-30 10:50:08, 2020-08-30 10:50:16)` .

Could some one take a look? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the event A:2020-08-30 10:50:10 could be late, it doesn't have to be. Watermarking is not necessarily deterministic.

In particular, the bounded-out-of-orderness watermark strategy uses a periodic watermark generator, that by default emits a new watermark every 200msec (of wall clock time). Your job doesn't run that long, so there's just one watermark happening at the end of the job, which closes all of the windows at once.

If you were to use a punctuated watermark generator rather than a periodic one, then you could have watermarks being generated at every conceivable opportunity (every time there's a new maximum timestamp). This would then behave deterministically, but at the expense of increasing the overhead, because the streams would have more watermarks for the operators to process.

Comment: Thanks @david-anderson for the great explanation， I overlooked the watermark generation strategy, `bounded-out-of-orderness watermark strategy uses a periodic watermark generator`, Thanks!